# App Engine Cron Job Always return HTTP status code 301

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-app-engine, cron

I have followed [this guide](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/ruby/scheduling-jobs-with-cron-yaml) to create cron job for my Rails app, but the HTTP status code is always returns 301 and my job status is failed. Am I missing something?

controller:

```
class CronsController < ApplicationController
  def example
    if request.headers["X-Appengine-Cron"]
      Example.do_something
      head :ok
    else
      head :not_found
    end
  end
end
```

routes:

```
get 'crons/example', to: 'crons#example'
```

cron.yaml

```
cron:
  - description: my cron example
  url: /crons/example
  schedule: every 2 hours from 03:00 to 07:00
```

result from `gcloud app logs read`

```
2017-08-26 07:00:05 default[20170823t153316]  "GET /crons/example" 301
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Two possibilities, both issues because app engine cron does not follow redirects:

- Does Rails add trailing slashes to routes by default? I had the same issue with Django and this turned out to be the cause. I updated the route in cron.yaml to include the trailing slash (in your case `url: /crons/example/`) and that fixed it.
- Is your application redirecting to https? If so, you may need to exempt this route.

Comment: thanks. I forgot my app has configuration `config.force_ssl = true` in production environment. It will make all non-https request to perform redirection.

Comment: Trailing slash is what got me. Thanks!

Comment: OMG, As soon as you mentioned `redirect` all the memories of struggling with this 5 months ago just came flooding back, thanks for the help