# Why is my python app's cron jobs always return a 301 response code?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask, cron

I have a Flask app for task management, using a cron job for notifying if a task is not yet taken. I use Google App Engine Standard Environment with python37 as my runtime.

It always returns a 301 response code.

I have tried the solutions proposed here [App Engine Cron Job Always return HTTP status code 301](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45892979/app-engine-cron-job-always-return-http-status-code-301).
But it still doesn't work.

```
handlers:
- url: /cron/non-yet-taken-jobs
  script: auto
```

```
cron:

- description: "check for non-taken jobs"
  url: /cron/non-yet-taken-jobs
  schedule: every 10 minutes synchronized
```

Comment: Where are you getting redirected to?

Comment: @IainShelvington the log doesn't give any details on that. If i access the api through postman or browser, it works. But not within GAE itself.

Comment: Did you try accessing the cron URL through postman or browser with http instead of https?  Do those return redirects?

Comment: @gaefan I have. Both are working. Based on the docs, if I don't specify the 'secure' parameter, as a default, it will allow both http and https connection.

"Both HTTP and HTTPS requests with URLs that match the handler succeed without redirects. The application can examine the request to determine which protocol was used, and respond accordingly. This is the default when secure is not provided for a handler."

Source: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/config/appref

Comment: May or may not help, but I had to force HTTP only calls on my cron jobs to get them to work even though everything is HTTPS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you set or use Cron within AppEngine, the calls that make only can be run over HTTP and not over HTTPS for this reason you are seeing the 301 code, this is a [known issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/118957573) , as is mentioned in the comments you can disable HTTPS, but i think that is [risky](https://www.chapterthree.com/blog/why-your-site-should-be-using-https).

I recommend you use a [Cloud Scheduler](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/) to perform your cron jobs, Cloud Scheduler supports HTTPS.

Or you can use micro f1-micro VM([always free](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier#always-free-usage-limits)) over compute engine to [run your cron jobs](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-add-jobs-to-cron-under-linux-or-unix-oses/) using curl in a bash script or using request in a python script.

Comment: though I still don't know why Cron does not work, but in the end I used Cloud Scheduler. Maybe I'll try using a separate VM for that in the future. Thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: according to this comment in the issue tracker, HTTPS is unnecessary when using calls internally

https://issuetracker.google.com/118957573#comment13

Comment: yes, but although i did not use https, and allow for http, it still did not work. I don't know if I implemented it wrong or smth.